# awk scan string for single quote character

Tags: bash, awk, solaris

I have a line and I want to know if it has any embedded single quote characters within it.  Using awk, I have tried several variants of

```
badix = index($0,"\047") -- this does not find it
badix = index($0, "'") -- throws a fit
badix = index($0, "\'") -- throws a fit
badix = index($0, \') -- throws a fit
```

This is for awk on Solaris 10, so gawk solutions won't apply in this case.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

You've got a shell quoting issue, where I suspect you are enclosing the `awk` command in single quotes, which cannot themselves include a single quote, even if escaped. Try `$'...'` quoting, which *can* include an escaped single quote:

```
awk $'{
    # Lots of other awk code...

    badix=index($0, "\'") }'

    # The rest of the awk code
   }'
```

Comment: Actually, this is a single line in a much larger awk script, which is called by a bash script.  the awk script already has the syntax awk '{a whole bunch of awk code ... this line of awk code ... morw awk code }'.  Tried your syntax without the awk, but it threw an error.

Comment: So you have something like `awk -f myscript.awk` in your bash script, and nothing except `awk` commands in `myscript.awk`?

Comment: That's a Bashism, though. Ok for a question tagged `bash` but perhaps worthy of a small caveat.

Comment: @JimR - based on your comment, it sounds like you are still passing the script to `awk` as a command-line argument, in which case the entire script must still be quoted properly.

Answer (score 7):

You should use:

```
badix = index($0, "'"'"'");
```

or use hex value `\x27` for single quote:

```
badix = index($0, "\x27");
```

Comment: @anubhava 4 double quotes and 3 single quotes to match a single quote? I am bit puzzled by this syntax. Could you please explain how this works? Kudos for figuring out this syntax by the way, this does work perfectly.

Comment: First, single quote is to exit out of single quoted awk command and last single quote is to enter again the single quoted awk command. `"'"` is for using a literal single quote. However I think `index($0, "\x27")` would be cleaner (answer edited)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a few ways:

Put the awk script in a separate file which you run with `-f`, in which case you avoid shell quotes, thus `"'"` will work

```
$ cat awkscript
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{print "'"}
$ awk -f awkscript </dev/null
'
$ chmod +x awkscript
$ ./awkscript </dev/null
'
```

Run it from a shell, where you enclose the script in ' quotes, end the ' quote, concat a literal ' quote, then start a new ' quote.

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "'\''"}' </dev/null
```

Use nawk instead, which is installed as `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`. It is posix compliant and much less useless.

```
PATH=/usr/xpg4/bin:$PATH
awk -v q=\' 'BEGIN{print q}'
awk 'BEGIN{print "\x27"}'
awk 'BEGIN{print "\047"}'
```

Comment: Actually, this is a single line in a much larger awk script, which is called by a bash script. the awk script already has the syntax awk '{a whole bunch of awk code ... this line of awk code ... morw awk code }'.  Surprised to learn that nawk is called awk in xpg4.  Will play with this a bit more tomorrow.